# Backbone.js server communication

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I'm learning backbone.js and I'm trying to understand how it communicates with a server. For example, if I wanted to call a .php script which returned some html, without using Backbone, just jQuery, I would:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', url: '/ajax.php',
    data: encodeURI('action=getsomedata&id=123'),
    success: function(html){ ... },
    error: function(){ ... }
});
```

I know that `ajax.php` is what I'm calling, I know that `data` is what I'm passing to the php, and I know that `html` contains the response.

I understand from doing some reading that Backbone can handle calls for data like this for me, but I don't understand how. Everything I have read seems to not explain it in terms I "get".

I know that `.save()` and `.fetch()` are available, and that I can set `url` to be my php file.

What I don't understand is where the name/value pairs `data` is and how to handle a response.

Any super simple examples of a Backbone Model, View and call for some data would be much appreciated.

Comment: check this for sample backbone implementation http://todomvc.com/examples/backbone/

Comment: It's also worth noting that Backbone is meant to talk to a REST-ful interface on the server.  This example has a plenty of code showing the interactions from that perspective.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797899/BackBone-Tutorial-Part-CRUD-Operations-on-Backbone